# Scroll through backgrounds while one background stays fixed for several scroll movements

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, css-position

[image]

I want to achieve the following effect:

When the page is first loaded div with background1.png is shown.
When the user starts to scroll, for a **defined amount of scroll movements**, this div stays visible and fixed.
When those movements end, the scrolling "continues" and the second div is starting to appear.

Edit:
I am adding a naive solution i tried, not sure if it's even in the right direction:

```
$(function() {  

    var staticSet = false;

    $(window).scroll(function() {            

        var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 

        if(currentScroll > '589' && staticSet==false){      
            staticSet = true;
            $('.calder').css('position','static');                                                              
        };                                                              
    });     
});
```

Basiclay, the first div starts with position:fixed, and when the scrolling reaches a certain
value,
 I make the div static. This ,however, won't achieve a smooth transition between the two divs.

Answer (score 0):

with `background-position: fixed` you can have the background stay in the same place even when you scroll

heres a fiddle demonstrating this http://jsfiddle.net/qTutn/

but i'm not sure if this fixes your problem ..

Comment: thanks. I know about Fixed. I've tried to use it in the scroll event, but the transition between backgrounds is not smooth.